# How can I debug: iostat shows 100 util but there's 0 read or write in iotop

Tags: ubuntu, io

The server is an AWS EC2 instance. Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. I have an EBS (`xvdf` is the device name) mounted to the instance. And this is the problem drive.

From iostat I see that drive is 100% utilized (see following: last row, to the very end).

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdb              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdf              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00 100.00
```

But from iotop it's super clear.

```
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :       0.00 B/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    3 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
    5 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/0:0H]
```

I tried to copy a file and it can copy but very very slow (<1M/s). So it's not a reporting issue and that drive is definitely having trouble.

Is there any insight where I can look into? or any other tool I can use to further investigate?

Comment: Using XFS, by any chance?  I've seen this problem of the "stuck IOP", where you've got 100% utilisation and the `avgqu-sz` is exactly 1 (or 2, if you're unlucky) using XFS.  Never got to the bottom of it; easier just to reboot the machine now and then when it happened.

Comment: Yes XFS! And yes reboot system works but it came back a few hours later.. Glad to know someone else there has the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: @womble do you happen to know if converting the drive to ext4 solves the problem?

Comment: No, the CTO of the place I was at had a huge hard-on for XFS, refused to let me convert.  However, I've *never* seen the problem on an ext4 filesystem, and I've run a *lot* more of those than I have XFS.  Given that you've got it happening so frequently, it sounds like you've got a perfect opportunity to do a test.

Comment: I'm planning to rebuild the drive with XFS first, to make sure the issue still exists (this is not a EBS snapshot restore, it's a new volume and rsync contents). If so I'll rebuild a EXT4 drive to test. If I found anything I'll let you know!

Comment: @womble During thanksgiving we actually received an email from aws. The EBS drive is dead. We have to recover our data from a snapshot. No details are provided by AWS. So my only takeaway is to backup data frequently!

Comment: EBS volumes are like un-RAIDed hard drives without SMART.  Don't trust 'em farther than you can throw 'em.